# How to authenticate a user via Spring Security and MarkLogic's Java Client API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, marklogic

What is best practice to validate if a user can be authenticated against a MarkLogic server (version 7.0.4) by using the Java Client API (2.0.4) for a login dialog securing a Spring web application?

With my current approach (see source code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikos/9c0ddd662b493738fbcc)) I am implementing a `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` from Spring Security ("classical" approach with HTTP sessions) where I do create a MarkLogic `DatabaseClient` instance, after which a simple query (`testQuery`, L. 46 in `MarkLogicConnections`) gets executed to see wether a result can be retrieved. From this result is is decided wether the login is granted or not.

I am wondering if there does exist a more elegant solution, but couldn't find anything in the MarkLogic documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use that opportunity to retrieve any user-specific data you're storing in the database.

If that isn't desirable, maybe there's no need to verify the user credentials at all? You could let that happen lazily on the first necessary query. And you should be prepared to handle database errors everywhere, in any case.

If you do need a non-lazy verification and don't want any data, that call to `suggest()` might be more expensive than you'd like. If so you might consider other options. A call to [`getErrorFormat`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/admin/ServerConfigurationManager.html#getErrorFormat%28%29) ought to be fairly cheap. Opening a transaction and then rolling it back should be cheap too, but it requires the `rest-writer` or `rest-admin` role. If nothing else works you could write an [extension](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices) that implements a noop XQuery, probably just `()`.

Comment: Thanks @mblakele for your answer, lazy verification is not an option (since this is all about a login mask, and directly have to decided if user is allowed to proceed or not). Since those "business" (read-only) users have neither `rest-writer` nor `rest-admin` role, I will probably stick with a simple suggest or search query to decided wether she is allowed to proceed or not.

Comment: Document retrieval is probably cheaper than search or suggest. You could use the opportunity to look for something like `"/usr/" + userId + "/data.xml"`. Maybe someday you'll want to keep something like user preferences there, but meanwhile it should be fairly cheap to request a document that doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a good point, still I consider this a "micro" optimization (since if the login takes 10 or 100ms for a intranet scenario it is not a big deal). I was really hoping for a way which allows to authenticate a user through the Java or REST API. There seem to be some helpful `xdmp` functions, which I might expose myself via an REST extension though...